# 1 form, 1 class based view, 2 models, how?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

My Idea is to have:

Parent/Child Model, Class Based View, one form in the template.

I'm open to any suggestion and I KNOW inline-formset is probably the right answer but every example I've found is years old, the Django documentation(v3.0) doesn't seem to differ from examples.

The closest I've so far managed to come is having the template show the children, I can get the parent in the same template but it isn't the same form.

Where am I going wrong or what base knowledge do I need to understand this?

Comment: The problem isn't really clear yet. You want to make a form which allows to edit the parent and all its children at the same time? Like in the admin, with Inlines?

Comment: @Blackeagle52 You are exactly right, I got the form to display and save under 1 button but i'm just trying to figure out the validation on formsets etc.
This is just a case of understanding the concepts as the official documentation is at 100mph and I think I need 1mph with easy examples to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, this link is about as close as possible

https://swapps.com/blog/working-with-nested-forms-with-django/

Class based views will handle the primary model set by

model = Parent

additional models can be loaded in context

context['second_form'] = ParentForm(instance=self.object)